# Can i upload more than 1GB video in spring boot

Tags: spring, video, upload, boot

Good morning. Which config do i need to put in place in application.properties file in order to be able to upload into database a video which sometimes can be larger than 1GB using spring boot? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! please take the [tour] and read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question

Comment: Have you read https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/#_tuning_file_upload_limits ?

Answer (score 0):

In spring 2.x, you can add the below config in properties file.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=2G
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=2G
```

But there is also limitation of max fiel size in nginx.
Add the below config in conf file if you use nginx to proxy.

```
locatin /(depends in your path)/{
   client_max_body_size    2048m;
}
```

Comment: I set spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1 meaning no limitation but each time i tried to save 932MB of video file in DB i got OutOfMemoryError. I really don't see how to fix it.

Comment: I also set java Heap space to -Xmx2048M but got same error.

Comment: Some sources suggest saving chunks of file bytes instead of whole file at once. I need a working example on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alright, it's not the problem of the configurations. 
Where did you deploy the application, on your pc  or on server?
OutOfMemoryError means no spare ram in your application, check to see if -Xxx2048M effective or you can try other jvm params like -Xss. Actually, I'm not familiar with jvm XD.